# Looking for Unix AWK command to perform full outer join of 2 files based on a common column (1st column in unix files is common)

Tags: shell, unix, awk

Looking for Unix AWK command to perform full outer join of 2 files based on a common column (1st column in Unix files is common)

1st File - app.txt

```
5.13.0.12S   Yes
5.13.0.11S   Yes
5.13.0.24S   Yes
5.13.0.23S   Yes
5.13.0.22S   Yes
```

1st File - db.txt

```
5.13.0.12S   WLPFO5_13_0_12S   WLPFO   incremental   2023-07-10_11:57:51   Activated   Current
5.13.0.11S   WLPFO5_13_0_11S   WLPFO   full          2023-07-10_06:37:32   Activated   Previous
```

Tried below AWK command. Did not work well (expecting result like - full outer join)

```
awk 'FNR==NR {data[$1]=$0; next} {$1=data[$1]}1' db.txt app.txt
```

Output of AWK -

```
5.13.0.12S   WLPFO5_13_0_12S   WLPFO   incremental   2023-07-10_11:57:51   Activated   Current Yes
5.13.0.11S   WLPFO5_13_0_11S   WLPFO   full          2023-07-10_06:37:32   Activated   Previous Yes
 Yes
 Yes
 Yes
```

for last 3 records, expecting Nulls then values (Yes) from app.txt

Please suggest ..
Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the expected output, don't just describe it.

Comment: To test a full outer join you should include in your example lines in `db.txt` that don't have a match in `app.txt`. You're getting answers that would not do a full outer join as they would discard such lines but they will produce the expected output given your current example.

Comment: Can `db.txt` ever be empty? Can `app.txt` ever have more than just 2 fields?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I've misunderstood, but here is one potential option using AWK:

```
awk 'FNR == NR {
    num_fields_db = NF
    data[$1] = $0
    next
}

{
    if ($1 in data) {
        print data[$1], $2
    } else {
        for (i = 1; i < num_fields_db; i++) {
            output = output "NULL" "\t"
        }
        print $1 "\t" output $2
        output = ""
    }
}' db.txt app.txt
5.13.0.12S  WLPFO5_13_0_12S  WLPFO  incremental  2023-07-10_11:57:51  Activated  Current   Yes
5.13.0.11S  WLPFO5_13_0_11S  WLPFO  full         2023-07-10_06:37:32  Activated  Previous  Yes
5.13.0.24S  NULL             NULL   NULL         NULL                 NULL       NULL      Yes
5.13.0.23S  NULL             NULL   NULL         NULL                 NULL       NULL      Yes
5.13.0.22S  NULL             NULL   NULL         NULL                 NULL       NULL      Yes
```

Or with GNU join:

```
join -e "NULL" -j1 -a1 -o 1.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7,1.2 <(sort app.txt) <(sort db.txt)
5.13.0.11S WLPFO5_13_0_11S WLPFO full 2023-07-10_06:37:32 Activated  Previous  Yes
5.13.0.12S WLPFO5_13_0_12S WLPFO incremental 2023-07-10_11:57:51 Activated  Current   Yes
5.13.0.22S NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL Yes
5.13.0.23S NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL Yes
5.13.0.24S NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL Yes

# tab delimited
join -e "NULL" -j1 -a1 -o 1.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7,1.2 <(sort app.txt) <(sort db.txt) | tr -s " " "\t"
5.13.0.11S  WLPFO5_13_0_11S  WLPFO  full         2023-07-10_06:37:32  Activated  Previous  Yes
5.13.0.12S  WLPFO5_13_0_12S  WLPFO  incremental  2023-07-10_11:57:51  Activated  Current   Yes
5.13.0.22S  NULL             NULL   NULL         NULL                 NULL       NULL       Yes
5.13.0.23S  NULL             NULL   NULL         NULL                 NULL       NULL       Yes
5.13.0.24S  NULL             NULL   NULL         NULL                 NULL       NULL       Yes
```

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` solution. Using `column` to get the output more clear form.

```
awk '
FNR==1 && NR==1{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    null=(null?null "\t":"") "NULL"
  }
}
FNR==NR{
  arr[$1]=$0
  next
}
{
  print ($1 in arr)?arr[$1] "\t" $2:$1 "\t" null
}
' db.txt app.txt | column -t
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use this `awk`:

```bash
awk '
FNR == NR {
   if (FNR == 1) {
      nulls = sprintf("%*s", NF-1, "");
      gsub(/ /, " NULL", nulls)
   }
   data[$1] = $0
   next
}
{
   print ($1 in data ? data[$1] : $1 nulls), $2
}' db.txt app.txt | column -t

5.13.0.12S  WLPFO5_13_0_12S  WLPFO  incremental  2023-07-10_11:57:51  Activated  Current   Yes
5.13.0.11S  WLPFO5_13_0_11S  WLPFO  full         2023-07-10_06:37:32  Activated  Previous  Yes
5.13.0.24S  NULL             NULL   NULL         NULL                 NULL       NULL      Yes
5.13.0.23S  NULL             NULL   NULL         NULL                 NULL       NULL      Yes
5.13.0.22S  NULL             NULL   NULL         NULL                 NULL       NULL      Yes
```

Here:

- For the first row in first file, using `sprintf`, we prepare a string with `NF-1` number of spaces in variable `nulls` first.
- Then using `gsub` we replace each space with `" NULL"` in variable `nulls`
- Store each row of `db.txt` in associative array `data` with key as `$1`
- Finally while processing `app.txt` we check presence of `$1` in associative array `data`
- If value is found in array then print `$1` and mapped value otherwise print variable $1 and `nulls`
- Use `column -t` to display output in tabular format.

Answer (score 2):

To do a full outer join using any POSIX awk would be:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    key = $1
    vals = $0
    sub(/[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+/,"",vals)
    if ( FNR == 1 ) {
        nomatch[++fileNr] = vals
        gsub(/[^[:space:]]+/,"Null",nomatch[fileNr])
    }
}
NR==FNR {
    file1[key] = vals
    next
}
{
    print $1, ($1 in file1 ? file1[$1] : nomatch[1]), vals
    delete file1[$1]
}
END {
    for ( key in file1 ) {
        print key, file1[key], nomatch[2]
    }
}
```

To test it modify your example to add lines to `db.txt` that don't have a shared key in `app.txt` and add additional fields to `app.txt`.

It assumes that every line from each file will have the same number of fields as the first line from that file. If that's not true then add whatever logic you want to handle that. If either input file could be empty then you'd need to add logic to define how many fields should be present in the output. It also assumes that the key value is unique in each input file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join`

```
join -a1 app.txt db.txt
```

output

```
5.13.0.12S Yes WLPFO5_13_0_12S WLPFO incremental 2023-07-10_11:57:51 Activated Current
5.13.0.11S Yes WLPFO5_13_0_11S WLPFO full 2023-07-10_06:37:32 Activated Previous
5.13.0.24S Yes
5.13.0.23S Yes
5.13.0.22S Yes
```